# how to display data in xml format in SSRS?

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I am working with `SSRS`. As we know, in `SSRS` the data can be displayed in the browser. But when data is displayed in the browser, it is in a table format.

Now, I want that when anyone clicks on `view report button`, the result gets shown in `xml` format.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the report runs, have the user export it as XML.

[image]